# Clojure keyword arguments

Tags: binding, clojure, lisp, common-lisp, params-keyword

In Common Lisp you can do this:

```
(defun foo (bar &key baz quux)
  (list bar baz quux))

(foo 1 :quux 3 :baz 2) ; => (1 2 3)
```

Clojure doesn't have keyword arguments.  One alternative is this:

```
(defn foo [bar {:keys [baz quux]}] 
  (list bar baz quux))

(foo 1 {:quux 3 :baz 2}) ; => (1 2 3)
```

That's too many nested brackets to have to type and read all the time.  It also requires an explicit hash-map to be passed in as an argument rather than a flat list.

What's the most idiomatic Clojure equivalent of keyword arguments that doesn't look someone set off a punctuation bomb?

Comment: Since this question was last active keyword destructuring binding has been added to Clojure. I have provided an answer to indicate this.

Comment: @Brian you should consider updating the accepted answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A simple way to simulate keyword args in clojure is using hash-map on rest parameters like this:

```
> (defn kwtest [x & e] (:foo (apply hash-map e)))
#'user/kwtest
> (kwtest 12 :bar "ignored" :foo "returned")
"returned"
```

Rich Hickey provided a macro in [this message from the clojure google group](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/51bb53ca077154f8) that gives you keyword parameters. The [corresponding thread](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/0aa57ab265f7474a/51bb53ca077154f8?#51bb53ca077154f8) contains information about why keyword parameters are not supported by clojure. Basically to avoid the runtime overhead. Rich explains the method I've shown above in [this message](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/msg/16487ce0cdab4c26)

Comment: See [Alex Stoddard's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717963/clojure-keyword-arguments/3969693#3969693); support for keyword args has been added into the parameter binding.

Answer (score 101):

To update this answer for Clojure 1.2 there is now full keyword arg support with defaults provided by the map forms of [destructuring binding](http://clojure.org/special_forms#binding-forms):

```
user> (defn foo [bar &{ :keys [baz quux] 
                        :or {baz "baz_default" quux "quux_default"}}]
         (list bar baz quux))
#'user/foo

user> (foo 1 :quux 3)
(1 "baz_default" 3)
```

Comment: I think this should be promoted to be the answer?

Answer (score 9):

A recent addition to `clojure.contrib.def` is the `defnk` macro, which enables definition of functions with keyword arguments (see [here](http://code.google.com/p/clojure-contrib/source/browse/trunk/src/clojure/contrib/def.clj?spec=svn946&r=890#119)).